# Can anything be done about unfortunate truncation in jobs sidebar?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

More than likely the answer is 'no' and rather has to do with the name of the company itself, but I just figured I'd bring this unfortunate situation to somebody's attention.  I know if it were my company though I'd rather it's name didn't appear as in the following depiction

> [image]

Comment: Well, maybe it's a shitty job and the company is just honest about it ;)

Comment: possibly the company's name is "SimplyAnalytics" and SO truncated the text due to limited space :)

Comment: Seems like it should be quite simple to implement a check, if truncated text ends with <blacklisted word> then truncate another character.

Comment: They could possibly put the location on a separate line, or maybe put it on the same line as the pay and treat Remote like a tag (I can't imagine that salary would vary too much in character length, unless a company decided to put something like $123,456.789 as their salary).

Comment: -1 There should have been a [red free hand circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/311398) around the company name. Now I don't know where to look.

Comment: Looks like there's a ton of space there, just waiting to be utilised.

Comment: Nah, George, FHCs are never redundant. Remember that [free hand circles are used to highlight free hand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138031/311398). ;)

Comment: *Expert JavaScript developer...who knows Javascript and ...erm... CSS*

Comment: They want a _backend sevice_.

Comment: Is the remote literal?

Comment: Maybe it would work with a different position?

Comment: I don't really see a purpose to truncating at all, certainly not after just 10 characters. Are company names so long that it's impossible to show the whole thing?

Comment: Looks like this has been "rect"ified ;) https://i.imgur.com/haDFeEF.png